# Django пагинатор теряет результат

Tags: django

У меня есть работающий пагинатор. Сейчас я делаю фильтры поиска и результат работает только на 1 странице. На последующих пагинатор сбивает результат. Как это пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**views.py**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    search_form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if search_form.is_valid():
        date1 = date(2000, 5, 2)
        date2 = date.today()
        contractor = None
        if search_form.cleaned_data['date1st']:
            date1 = search_form.cleaned_data['date1st']
        if search_form.cleaned_data['date2st']:
            date2 = search_form.cleaned_data['date2st']
        print(date1)
        print(date2)
        paymentsss = Transaction.objects.select_related('currency', 'payment_source__payment_type', 'deal__service',
                                                        'deal__service__contractor').filter(
            payment_date__range=[date1, date2], ).order_by('-id')
        if search_form.cleaned_data['contractorName']:
            contractor = search_form.cleaned_data['contractorName']
            paymentsss = paymentsss.filter(deal__service__contractor__name=contractor)
        search_form = SearchForm()
        paginator = Paginator(paymentsss, 25)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            payments = paginator.get_page(page)
        except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage, PageNotAnInteger):
            payments = paginator.page(1)
        data = {'payments': payments, 'form': search_form}
        return render(request, "payments.html", data)
```

**HTML-код**

```
    <ul class="pagination pg-primary">

{% if payments.has_previous %}
     <li class="page-item">
         <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ payments.1 }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
         </a>
     </li>
{% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ payments.1 }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
         </a>
     </li>
{% endif %}
    {% if payments.has_previous %}
     <li class="page-item">
         <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
         </a>
     </li>
{% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled" >
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
         </a>
     </li>
{% endif %}


{% for i in payments.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if payments.number == i %}
    <li class="page-item active"><a class ="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% elif i > payments.number|add:'-5' and i < payments.number|add:'5' %}
       <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ i }}" class="page-link">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if payments.has_next %}
 <li class="page-item">
         <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ payments.page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
     </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item disabled">
         <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ payments.page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
     </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if payments.has_next %}
 <li class="page-item">
         <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ payments.paginator.num_pages }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
     </li>
    {% else %}
     <li class="page-item disabled">
         <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ payments.paginator.num_pages }}" aria-label="Previous">
             <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>
             <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
     </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте поиск через GET и добавляйте параметны поиска к ссылкам в пагинаторе.

Не работает потому что отправляя POST запрос вы фильтруете записи, но только на странице, на которой отправили запрос. Нажимая на кнопку в пагинаторе - вы переходите на другую страницу, которая понятия не имеет, что за формы была отправлена ранее. Ей надо сообщать о том, что была фильтрация (ну или сортировка) по тем или иным полям и данным. Проще это сделать через GET запросы и параметры.

```
{% for link in paginator_links %} {# Не помню, как из пагинатора получать ссылки, ибо редко с ним работаю, но это не важно #}
  <a href="{{link.url}}?{{link_querystring}}">{{link.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

`link_querystring` можно собрать заранее из данных формы и затем поместить в контекст

---

Если вам не нравится GET запросы и их вид ссылок, или хотите через POST, то используйте AJAX. Для AJAX вам нужно поставить обработчики на кнопки пагинатода, чтобы на адрес пагинатора отправлялся POST запрос с данными для фильтрации сортировки.

Например

```
btns.on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'), 
        method: 'post',
        data: search_form_data,
        success: function (data) { content.html(data); }
    });
});
```

---

Для справки: в django админке пагинатор работает через GET-запросы